# Not getting "Detail" section of unique constraint error when row level security in effect

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, row-level-security

TL;DR: On Postgres 10.6 When row level security is in effect - I'm not getting the "DETAIL" section of a unique constraint violation error even though that role can see/insert all rows.

I have 2 roles: `admin` (owner of the tables) and `app_role` on which row level security is in effect.

Here's how to reproduce:

```
--using the admin role
create table parents(
    parent_id int primary key, 
    parent_name text unique
);
create table childs(
    child_id int primary key, 
    child_name text, 
    parent_id int references parents (parent_id), 
    constraint childs_uq unique (parent_id, child_name)
);

insert into parents values(1,'aaa');
insert into childs values(1,'bbb',1);
insert into childs values(2,'bbb',1);
--SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "childs_uq"
--  Detail: Key (parent_id, child_name)=(1, bbb) already exists.
```

Note the "Detail: Key (parent_id, child_name)=(1, bbb) already exists."

The `app_role` role was given the following grants and RLS policies:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON parents TO app_role;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON childs TO app_role;

CREATE POLICY parents_select
ON parents 
AS permissive
FOR SELECT
TO app_role
USING (true);

alter table parents enable row level security;

CREATE POLICY childs_select
ON childs 
AS permissive
FOR SELECT
TO app_role
USING (true);

CREATE POLICY childs_insert
ON childs 
AS permissive
FOR INSERT
TO app_role
WITH CHECK (true);

alter table childs enable row level security;
```

Now for the problem:

```
--using `app_role`
insert into childs values(3,'ccc',1); -- works

insert into childs values(2,'bbb',1);
--SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "childs_uq"
```

The error does not contain the "Detail" section.

Is it a bug? Expected behavior (would love to see a documentation reference)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as <strike>designed</strike>implemented and is documented in [`src/backend/access/index/genam.c`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/access/index/genam.c;h=42aaa5bad62c9054767b54517dd48dc493ffd98b;hb=HEAD#l204), in the comments to function `BuildIndexValueDescription`:

```c
char *
BuildIndexValueDescription(Relation indexRelation,
                           Datum *values, bool *isnull)
{
[...]
    /*
     * Check permissions- if the user does not have access to view all of the
     * key columns then return NULL to avoid leaking data.
     *
     * First check if RLS is enabled for the relation.  If so, return NULL to
     * avoid leaking data.
     *
     * Next we need to check table-level SELECT access and then, if there is
     * no access there, check column-level permissions.
     */
[...]
    /* RLS check- if RLS is enabled then we don't return anything. */
    if (check_enable_rls(indrelid, InvalidOid, true) == RLS_ENABLED)
        return NULL;
```

The problem with showing the detail is obvious:

If you know which key your entry conflicts with, you may get some information about rows in the database that you cannot see.

This may seem unnecessary in the context of a primary key conflict, because you know what the conflicting values are, even if you don't get the detail message, but the case is different with – say – an exclusion constraint. It seems like nobody cared enough to make a distinction.

Also there *could* be a check if you can see the conflicting row or not and you *could* get the detail message in the former case, but it seems like nobody bothered.

Comment: Thanks for the source reference. I guess I was expecting the "_could_" to be implemented. Would have been nice if it worked the same.

Comment: You can try to write a patch for that, but I don't know how complicated it would be. Anything that would add extra execution time for the non-conflicting case has a good chance of being rejected.